# Create multiple lists of unique entries from master list in c#

Tags: c#

I need to process an outbound SMS queue and create batches of messages. The queued list might contain multiple messages to the same person. Batches do not allow this, so I need to run through the main outbound queue and create as many batches as necessary to ensure they contain unique entries.
Example:

```
Outbound queue = (1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9)
```

results in...

```
 batch 1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    batch 2 = (3,7,8)
    batch 3 = (7,8)
batch 4 = (8)
```

I can easily check for duplicates but I'm looking for a slick way to generate the additional batches.

Thanks!

Comment: You are talking about batches and messages, are these collections? If so, which kind of collections(f.e. `int[]` or `List<int>`)? That you are using terms like _queue_ is just confusing if it's not important for your issue. If possible provide compiling code that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where were you stuck? This seems easy to do. Show your code, so that you can get a specific answer.

Comment: I'm still not sure if i have understood it correctly. Why do you have 4 batches instead of 3? First contains all distinct numbers, second contains all with appear at least two times, third contains all which appear at least three times, but that's only 8. What's in batch 3?

Comment: @Tim OP wants to divide all input over the batches, so that each batch contains distinct values. OP's result for batch 3 is wrong, it should only contain an `8`, as there's only 2 `7`s in the input which are in batch 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this approach using  `Enumerable.ToLookup` and other LINQ methods:

```
var queues = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9 };
var lookup = queues.ToLookup(i => i);
int maxCount = lookup.Max(g => g.Count());
List<List<int>> allbatches = Enumerable.Range(1, maxCount)
    .Select(count => lookup.Where(x => x.Count() >= count).Select(x => x.Key).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Result is a list which contains four other `List<int>`:

```
foreach (List<int> list in allbatches)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
3, 7, 8
8
8
```

Comment: But there's 4 `8`s in the input. Each batch should contain an `8` and there should be 4 batches.

Comment: @CodeCaster: At last the penny's dropped! Edited my answer to provide a LINQ only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific data structures used, the Linq [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method could be used (provided that the queue implements `IEnumerable<T>` for some type `T`) for grouping by the same user; afterwards, the groups can be iterated separately.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to walk over the input, creating and filling the batches as you go:

```
private static List<List<int>> CreateUniqueBatches(List<int> source)
{
    var batches = new List<List<int>>();

    int currentBatch = 0;

    foreach (var i in source)
    {
        // Find the index for the batch that can contain the number `i`
        while (currentBatch < batches.Count && batches[currentBatch].Contains(i))
        {
            currentBatch++;
        }

        if (currentBatch == batches.Count)
        {
            batches.Add(new List<int>());
        }

        batches[currentBatch].Add(i);
        currentBatch = 0;
    }

    return batches;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
3, 7, 8
8
8
```

I'm sure this can be shortened or written in a functional way. I've tried using GroupBy, Distinct and Except, but couldn't figure it out that quickly.